# MoleculePlot always returns an empty plot

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, chemistry

**Bug introduced in 12.1.0, persisting through 13.0 and fixed in 13.1**

---

```
MoleculePlot@Molecule["O=C(C1CCC1)S[C@@H]1CCC1(C)C"]
```

This is a documented example usage of `MoleculePlot`, but it returns a `Graphics` expression that is gray everywhere.

```
PacletFind["Chemistry"][[1]]["Version"]
(* 12.2.31 *)
```

---

I confirmed that this is a bug. It occurs in certain situations. The following code produces the scene I've seen:

```
With[{def = Options[$FrontEnd, DefaultStyleDefinitions]},
  DownValues@Chemistry`MoleculePlot`LabelGraphics`Private`labelGraphics = Last@DownValues@Chemistry`MoleculePlot`LabelGraphics`Private`labelGraphics};
  SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DefaultStyleDefinitions->"Package.nb"];
  Print@MoleculePlot@Molecule["O=C(C1CCC1)S[C@@H]1CCC1(C)C"];
  SetOptions[$FrontEnd, def];
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue seems to happen when the default style definitions have a different background color.  This will be fixed in an upcoming version. Either of the following should serve as a workaround:

```
Molecule;
SetOptions[Chemistry`MoleculePlot`MoleculePlot2D`Private`MoleculePlotMethod, "TextGraphics" -> False]
```

or

```
With[{
  ilg = Chemistry`MoleculePlot`LabelGraphics`Private`iLabelGraphics2,
  tfc = Chemistry`MoleculePlot`LabelGraphics`Private`transformFilledCurves},
  Molecule;
  DownValues[ilg] = 
   DownValues[ilg] /. 
    tfc -> Composition[Cases[#, {__, _FilledCurve}] &, tfc];
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`` Chemistry`MoleculePlot`LabelGraphics`Private`labelGraphics `` use `UsingFrontEnd` and `ExportPacket` to generate a `Graphics` of a string, which make the result being dependent on the front-end option `Background`. When it's not `None`, the front-end will generate a `Polygon` of that color, which covers the whole `MoleculePlot`.

It does memorization. For a correct output, we have to clean the wrong cache of it by assigning `DownValues`.

I'm not sure of whether it had been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: I had to edit the post, since the way it was written it rendered my front end not usable (`Options[symbol, optionName]` returns `optionName -> value`).  I think what you have written here should be added to the question rather than as an answer.  Finally, are you saying the issue only comes up when you have the stylesheet set to `"Package.nb"`?

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks for the edit. I wrote the method to replicate it in the answer because I do not know how to replicate it before being able to answer this question. I'll move it to the question to help readers replicate it eazily.