# Incorrect result of PDF

Tags: probability-or-statistics

The execution of the command

```
r = PDF[TransformedDistribution[x*y, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}], t]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{2} & 0<t<1 \\
>  0 & t>1\lor t<0 \\
>  \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
> \end{cases} $$

brings an incorrect result in view of

```
Integrate[r, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `1/2`

whereas I was learned this integral must equal one. This implies the discordance between

```
CentralMoment[TransformedDistribution[x*y, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}], 2]
```

> `5/48`

and

```
Integrate[(t - 1/4)^2*r, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `7/96`

In the above

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[x*y, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
y\[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]]
```

> `1/4`

and the the same definitions from [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Moment)
and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) are used.

I am sure that the PDF `r` does not exist because

```
CDF[TransformedDistribution[x*y, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}], t]
```

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2} & t=0 \\
 1 & t\geq 1 \\
 \frac{t+1}{2} & 0<t<1
\end{cases} $$

is not an absolutely continuous function. Am  I not right?

Comment: It appears that *Mathematica* does not always play well when mixing continuous and discrete distributions (which is what you have).  Notice that the initial pdf doesn't include the probability mass at zero (i.e., $t=0$ is not included).  For example, the documentation for `MixtureDistribution` explicitly states that the distribution mixtures must be all continuous or all discrete.

Comment: @JimB: Thank you for your response. I don't use `MixtureDistribution`. The documentation to `TransformedDistribution` does not states that the transformed distributions must be all [absolutely] continuous or all discrete. Also `PDF[TransformedDistribution[x*y, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2, 3}]}], t]` is OK.

Comment: BTW, the notion of PDF for a discrete distribution is not standard, e.g. [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Discrete_distribution) and Harald Cramér in Mathematical Methods of Statistics do not use it (Harald Cramér uses the notion "probability distribution".).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's essentially a bug report that should be directed to WRI.  Tacking on "Am I right?" at the end doesn't really make it a question suited for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @chuy: Disagree. This is a normal question. Maybe, something is not taken into account by me. Maybe, there is a workaround.

Comment: @chuy: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/moleculeplot-always-returns-an-empty-plot) is a question of that sort.