# MoleculePlot is completely unfunctional when DefaultStyleDefinitions sets to ReverseColor.nb

Tags: bugs, color, stylesheet, chemistry, plot-themes

If you set the DefaultStyleDefinitions sets to ReverseColor.nb
[image]

then when you try to execute the example from the MoleculePlot document[image],

your MoleculePlot will have blank result like

[image]

even if you switch to default stylesheet manually. the result is still broken

[image]

However, the MoleculePlot works fine if you set DefaultStyleDefinitions to Default.nb
then switch to ReverseColor stylesheet manually.

[image]

this means ReverseColor.nb actually can fit the MoleculePlot well,
but somehow is clearly wrong when set as DefaultStyleDefinitions.

So my question is :
Is this a bug?
If so, how to fix it?
If not, then how to set the ReverSecolor.nb stylesheet as the default stylesheet and works with MoleculePlot function properly?

Comment: I can reproduce this, I think it is the same issue as in [MoleculePlot always returns an empty plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/257117/9490).  I give two workarounds in an answer there, can you see if they work for you?

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks, this code actually works.